# asyncExec method is not calling run method of Runnable class

Tags: java, swing, swt

I want to embed microsoft word in Jframe in java . That is why I have the following code :

```
public class AbrirWordJFrame {
    static OleClientSite clientSite;
    static OleFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        JFrame jframe=new JFrame("Mi jframe");
        final Canvas canvas=new Canvas();
        jframe.getContentPane().add(canvas);
        jframe.setSize(800, 600);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println("Before Async"); 

        display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("In Async method");
                Shell shell = SWT_AWT.new_Shell(display, canvas);
                shell.setSize(800, 600);

                //abrimos un word
                shell.setText("Word Example");
                shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
                try {
                    frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
                    //esto abre un documento existente
                    clientSite = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NULL, new File("prueba.doc"));
                    //esto abre un documento en blanco
//                  clientSite = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "Word.Document");
                    addFileMenu(frame);
                } catch (SWTError e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to open activeX control");
                    display.dispose();
                    return;
                }
                //fin abrimos un word
                //abrimos un navegador
//              Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
//              browser.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
//              browser.setSize(800, 600);
//              browser.setUrl("http://www.google.com");
                //fin abrimos un navegador
                shell.open();

            }
        }); 

       // display d= new Display(new runnable);


        //el titulo
//      shell.setText("Word Example");
//      shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
//      try {
//          frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
//          //esto abre un documento existente
//          clientSite = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NULL, new File("prueba.doc"));
//          //esto abre un documento en blanco
////            clientSite = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "Word.Document");
//          addFileMenu(frame);
//      } catch (SWTError e) {
//          System.out.println("Unable to open activeX control");
//          display.dispose();
//          return;
//      }
//      shell.setSize(800, 600);
//      shell.open();
//      
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            /*if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();*/
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    static void addFileMenu(OleFrame frame) {
        final Shell shell = frame.getShell();
        Menu menuBar = shell.getMenuBar();
        if (menuBar == null) {
            menuBar = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
            shell.setMenuBar(menuBar);
        }
        MenuItem fileMenu = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);
        fileMenu.setText("&File");
        Menu menuFile = new Menu(fileMenu);
        fileMenu.setMenu(menuFile);
        frame.setFileMenus(new MenuItem[] { fileMenu });

        MenuItem menuFileOpen = new MenuItem(menuFile, SWT.CASCADE);
        menuFileOpen.setText("Open...");
        menuFileOpen.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                fileOpen();
            }
        });
        MenuItem menuFileExit = new MenuItem(menuFile, SWT.CASCADE);
        menuFileExit.setText("Exit");
        menuFileExit.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                shell.dispose();
            }
        });
    }

    static void fileOpen() {
        FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(clientSite.getShell(), SWT.OPEN);
        dialog.setFilterExtensions(new String[] { "*.doc" });
        String fileName = dialog.open();
        if (fileName != null) {
            clientSite.dispose();
            clientSite = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "Word.Document", new File(fileName));
            clientSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exceptions :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at AbrirWordJFrame.main(AbrirWordJFrame.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at AbrirWordJFrame$1.run(AbrirWordJFrame.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

But asyncExec method is not calling run method of runnable class . I have searched a lot in the internet  and found nothing . please help me .

Answer (score 2):

You are not running the SWT event dispatch loop, you must run this for `asyncExec` (and many other parts of SWT) to work.

You have:

```
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    /*if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();*/
}
```

Those commented out lines are the event dispatch loop. You must call:

```
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
  if (!display.readAndDispatch())
    display.sleep();
}
```

**But** you are mixing Swing and SWT - you should not do this as it is very difficult to get to work properly. Use either Swing or SWT but not both. You can use the `SWT_AWT` class to call Swing code from SWT but this should be a last resort.

Comment: The question is slightly edited . Please see the updated question .

Comment: If I remove the comment , then I have got exception which is stated in the question

Comment: Something wrong with your OleClientSite constructor, I don't know anything about that.

Comment: I am trying this questions answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883937/open-ms-documents-into-jframe

Comment: I don't know because this is a Windows only API and I don't run Windows. You are getting `IllegalArgumentException` from something in the constructor so something is wrong - perhaps the `File` argument must reference a file that actually exists or something like that.

Comment: I have created a docx in project folder . Then this error is removed . But now widgetSelected method of SelectionAdapter class is not called . Do you know why ?